# Action of the negative Cartan-Weyl generators on a highest weight element

Tags: rt.representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras, root-systems

Let $\frak{g}$ be a complex simple Lie algebra of rank $l$. For $\frak{h}$ a choice of Cartan subalgebra, let $\alpha_1, \cdots, \alpha_r$ be the corresponding choice of simple roots, $X_{\alpha_i}, H_{\alpha_i}, X_{-\alpha_i}$ the Cartan--Weyl basis, and $\pi_1, \cdots, \pi_l$ the fundamental weights. For the irreducible $\frak{g}$-module $V(\pi_k)$ let $v \in V(\pi_k)$ be a highest weight vector, i.e.
$$
X_{\alpha_i}v = 0 ~~ \forall i=1, \dots, r.
$$
How will the elements $X_{-\alpha_i}$ act on $v$? Initial experiments suggest that
$$
X_{-\alpha_i}v = 0, ~~ \forall i \neq k.
$$
However I cannot seem to see a general proof. Any help is very appreciated.

Comment: Should $F_{\alpha_i}$ be $X_{-\alpha_i}$?

Comment: Are you sure this is true in Type $B_2$?

Comment: As pointed out by @LSpice you seem to be conflating two of the (three) standard notations for the generators: $X_{\alpha}, H_{\alpha}, X_{-\alpha}$ and $E_{\alpha},H_{\alpha}, F_{\alpha}$.

Comment: Sorry for the typo, it has been fixed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let α be a simple root that is not α<sub>k</sub>. Associated to this simple root is a subalgebra isomorphic to $\mathfrak{sl}_2$. For this subalgebra, an element of weight ω<sub>k</sub> has weight zero. In the fundamental representation you are considering, such an element is highest weight by assumption and therefore by the classificaition of representations of $\mathfrak{sl}_2$ is annihilated by F<sub>α</sub>.

Comment: Nice answer, thanks a lot! So it seems that there is nothing special about the $V(\pi_k)$-case, that is to say, for any highest weight vector in $V(\lambda)$, where $\lambda = \sum_i a_i\pi_i$, we have $X_{\alpha_i}v = 0$ whenever $a_i = 0$?